# Are linux socket kernel buffers swapped to disk?

Tags: linux, sockets, kernel, buffer

This may seem like a dense question, but does anyone know if linux socket kernel buffers are swapped to disk?

I can't image they are, like all kernel code. Looking at the vmm it looks like their not. However, searching for a definitive answer, I disturbingly found conflicting statements.

Anyone know for sure ? I would hate to have to do a long deep dive to find it does, if someone already knows.

thanks

Comment: I'm hoping for a kernel developer that knows this area to answer.

Comment: If you knew the answer, what would it enable you to do? (I ask because I'm curious how it makes a difference)

Comment: Sorry it took so long, the day job and the flu...
 I'm designing a high performance rest interface and framework, written in C. I'm using unix sockets as a IPC. I don't want these buffers swapped to disk, the performance degradation is appalling.

Comment: The design is to support 10ge and 40gbit infiniband interconnect at at a minimum. But, there are gains found in under powered edge devices like smart phones and pads.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, all kernel memory is not swappable (a.k.a. pageable) in linux.

Comment: Do you have a citation?